# show a spanned set is a basis of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

let $F$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$ that spanned by 
$S$ = $\{u = (1,1,0,0), v=(1,0,-1,0), w=(0,0,1,1)\}$

the question is show that $S$ is a basis of $F$

Comment: Well, since $F$ is spanned by $S$, all you have to do is check that $u,v,w$ are linearly independent, and that will make it a basis of $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis of a set is just a set of linearly independent vectors which span the set. These span the set, so you just need to show they are linearly independent, that is $$\alpha \vec u+\beta \vec v+\gamma\vec w=\vec 0\implies\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0.$$
Comparing second entries, $\alpha=0$.
Then comparing first entries, $\alpha+\beta=0\implies\beta=0$. Finally comparing fourth entries, $\gamma=0$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

If you let $x\cdot u + y\cdot v + z\cdot w=0$, the only solution to it is $x=y=z=0$

Answer (score 1):

S is a basis of F if it matches these two conditions:

1.S spans F

2.S consist of a set of linearly independent vectors.

The first condition is already satisfied. 
A set of vectors are linearly independent if the matrix with these vectors as columns has a non-zero determinant.

So you just have to calculate the determinant :)

( There are other ways to check independency )

Answer (score 0):

We have to show that they are linearly independent. To do this, called

$$A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

we show that $r(A)=3$, with $r(A)$ indicating the rank of the matrix $A$.

Applying the Gaussian elimination method (multiply the second row by $-1$ and add the first row), you find that the rank is $3$.